# Scattering of unpolarized light

Tags: optics, scattering, polarization

I am doing an experiment in which I want to get $\mathrm{I}$ intensity of light at an angle $\theta$, from the original path of unpolarized light of intensity $\mathrm{I}$ after scattering from a point. It seems that $\theta$ is coming nearby $\mathrm{45}^\circ$ from the perpendicular to original path of light. Intensity of $\dfrac{\mathrm{I}}{2}$ is observed perpendicular to original path.

Is there any law that governs the same? Is the light obtained in two cases polarised (I am not allowed to use polarimeter to check polarity of incoming light and am neither supposed to tell that)?

I have clicked picture from screen of lab computer, if someone improve the quality of image, it will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If you include a drawing in your question it will be easier to answer.  This appears to be a homework problem, and should be tagged as such if it is.

Comment: @S.McGrew I am eighth grade student, don't bother about homework problem. Ok I will add

Comment: On what are you scattering the light off?

Comment: Details of the experiment make a big difference.  For example, the intensity of light measured at any angle will depend on the distance between the point of scatter and the light detector.  Different types of scattering materials will scatter different percentages of light into different directions.  Some kinds of materials (e.g., opal glass or a thick layer of glass beads) will depolarize the light.  Other kinds may just alter the polarization; and other kinds (e.g., Rayleigh scattering in the atmosphere) may selectively scatter light of particular polarization into particular angles.